# Free gadget to group desktop icons

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

Is there a free gadget to group desktop icons in Windows 7?

Something akin to commercial [Ve Best Icon Groups](http://www.vebest.com/products/shell-desktop/best-icon-groups.html).

Fine even if it's simpler, as long as:

- the icons can be dragged to the group to be added
- they are all shown and can be opened with a single click

In case there isn't, any kind of automatic organizer better than the default "keep icons arranged" could suffice. Something like being able to arrange some on the left and some on the right (and keep them arranged there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) might be a viable approach here.

[image]

Comment: Fences is not a free alternative (at least, not anymore)

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia true, but the question was about Windows 7, not Windows 8. I have to assume the old free version still just works on 7, doesn't it?

Comment: @Lohoris I think so, if you can manage to get the version 2 installer. If I'm not wrong, it started being paid since version 3.